# jquery cancel button text change.I required "NO" instead of "Cancel"

Tags: jquery, dialog

```
  $("#dvdialogconfirm").text(msg);
        $("#dvdialogconfirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            zIndex: 100001,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            width: 360,
            buttons: {
                OK: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    if (func != null) {
                        func();
                    }
                },
                Cancel:
                    function () {
                    func1();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Just change Cancel as "No"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#dvdialogconfirm").text(msg); 
  $("#dvdialogconfirm").dialog({ 
     resizable: false, 
     modal: true, 
     zIndex: 100001, 
     closeOnEscape: false, 
     width: 360, 
     buttons: { 
        YES: function () { 
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
                if (func != null) {
                    func(); 
                 } 
             }, 
        NO: function () { 
             func1(); 
            } 
     } 
  });
```

I think this one help you.

Comment: Thank you for your kind support.This is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the button text by changing the objects as you require. Suppose you want it to be a "Yes" or "No" dialogue box then :

```
$("#dvdialogconfirm").text(msg);
        $("#dvdialogconfirm").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            zIndex: 100001,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            width: 360,
            buttons: {
                Yes: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    if (func != null) {
                        func();
                    }
                },
                No:
                    function () {
                    func1();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind support.This is working fine.